# how to increment character in scala

Tags: scala

I am writing a code to print all characters and its ascii value from 'a' to 'z'.

With the following code snippet I am able to do this.

```
var c = 'a'
while(c < 'z'){
    println(c +" = " + c.toInt)
    var p = c.toInt
    p += 1
    c = p.toChar
}
```

But when I am doing following(like c)

```
var c = 'a'
while(c < 'z'){
    println(c +" = " + c.toInt)
    c += 1 // or c = c + 1.toChar
}
```

it is giving me following error

```
 found   : Int
 required: Char
```

Is there any better way to increment character in scala.

Thanks,
Shantanu

Comment: Just a quick question, is there a reason for not doing `('a' to 'z').foreach(println)` for your basic task, which is printing ASCII values from a to z?

Comment: for me ('a' to 'z').foreach(println) is printing a to z only, not ASCII values.

Comment: Ohh damn, I misunderstood. You have to add `.map(_.toInt)` before `foreach` then.

Comment: yes. This is nicer way to do this. Thanks. But my main motive for this question is to find out the alternatives for incrementing characters.

Comment: Hi Patryk, Please add your comment as answer. This seems the best way to do this.

Comment: Done! You've got plenty of options in the answers now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As requested, here's yet another option moved from comments:

```
('a' to 'z').map(_.toInt).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Whoops. Sorry, didn't read your comments when I posted my answer.

Answer (score 5):

In Scala you can make an iterable `Range` using the expression `'a' to 'z'`

```
('a' to 'z').foreach(println)
```

[Try it](http://www.scalakata.com/52bebf27e4b0b1a1c4dc03c2)

Answer (score 2):

Another take is to use Streams. Besides being more modular (you can continue conting, map it etc.) it can prove quite efficient to compute things lazily. In this case it's not relevant. But I should be studying for an exam, so I have to spend mandatory slacking-time somwhere...

```
  val s = Stream.from('a').map(_.toChar)
  s.take(26).force
> Stream(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z)
```

Or as a single-liner

```
Stream.from('a').map(_.toChar).take(26).force
```

Or with a condition

```
Stream.from('a').map(_.toChar).takeWhile(_ <= 'z').force
```

The example can be seen here: http://www.scalakata.com/52bec5a5e4b0b1a1c4dc0402 (Nice tool btw, thanks @theon!)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var c = 'a'
while(c < 'z'){
  println(c +" = " + c.toInt)
  c = (c + 1).toChar
}
```

But it's a hideous use of a `var` though, I'd advise one of the other solutions.

Comment: using var in the example is ugly, but this solution is the one that best addresses the actual question. The original question was about how to increment chars - using "toChar" to convert back to a char is the relevant bit :  (c+1) .toChar

Answer (score 0):

This is not nearly as awesome as @theon's answer, but here is a for-comprehension version:

```
scala> for(i <- 'a' to 'z') print(i.toString + ' ')
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```